# extract jmeter performance metrics

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I can use Aggregate Report listener to generate the Aggregate Report with performance metrics by giving the output jtl file in csv format. By clicking on "Save Table Data" button, I can save the metrics data into csv file.

How can I do that in a command/programming way?

The command
jmeter -g -l  -o 
would create the report but the metrics data is embedded in the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

1. Install Command-Line Graph Plotting tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line Plotting Tools]
2. Execute the following script from Jmeter's "bin" folder

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv Aggregate.csv --input-jtl your_test_results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
3. That's it, you should have Aggregate Report data equivalent in the `Aggregate.csv` file.